# Allow uploaded images as replies in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, reply

In chat, almost everything works as a reply to a specific message, including oneboxes. The only thing that doesn't seem to work as a reply is an uploaded image. Even if I hit the reply button before uploading the image, it will always be posted like an empty message.

Curiously, even if I post an image that has already been uploaded, as a link, such that it oneboxes, I can do so as a reply. Apart from the little reply-arrow, this even looks identical to a freshly uploaded image (and I suspect that behind the scenes, uploading actually does just generate a onebox to the uploaded image's link).

So I guess I can currently work around this, by uploading the image first (e.g. by inserting it into a post on main which I then never submit), and then posting the link as a reply, but that seems rather like a rather annoying workflow.

So would it be possible, to take replies into account when uploading images, too?

Comment: Another work-around: edit the message afterward to insert the `:msgid` prefix. That's a lot easier with [SE Chat Modifications -- Keyboard navigation and commands for chat](http://stackapps.com/q/2105) installed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I didn't know you could edit messages due to uploads. I guess that's a feasible workaround, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Upload the image as you always do
2. Click "edit" or your up-arrow

   > [image]
3. Click this arrow to reply

   > [image]

   (or select "reply to this message" in the popup which appears by clicking down-arrow)

   > [image]
4. You'll see something like this:

   > [image]

   Hit ur <kbd>Enter</kbd>!